# Поиск по словам и цифрам full text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Друзья ситуация такова, нужно найти в бд любые слова которые соответствуют словам из запроса. Вот пример запроса:

```
$filter .=" AND MATCH (owner) AGAINST ('*".$word."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

В данный момент $word = "ООО";

В БД поле owner равно к примеру ООО "СЗТком". В результате выполнения данного запроса я не получаю ничего. Если $word = "сзт" к примеру, то строку находит.

Если к примеру у меня поле owner равно "1 ФМС" то когда слово $word = "1" или к примеру "ФМС" - результат 0 строк. тоесть поиск не происходит.

Вопрос как отредактировать запрос таким образом что бы он искал все возможные варианты по 1 или второму слову, но не точному вхождению? Важно что бы поиск осуществлялся также и по цифрам

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что полнотекстовый поиск по умолчанию работает только по 4+ символов? Т.е. 3 символа недостаточно для поиска, нужно 4 или более?

Answer (score 0):

Full TEXT ищет по словам. Словом обычно понимается совокупность из не менее 3-х не пробельных символов (но это может быть изменено) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Судя по вашим запросам вам и не очень то и нужен полнотекстовый поиск. Вам больше LIKE подходит.